# Solve system with lower triangular and Toeplitz matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, toeplitz-matrices

I have a matrix equation that looks like:

\begin{equation}
O = RIA 
\end{equation}

Where my matrices have the following properties:

- $R$: Lower triangular and Toeplitz matrix. Max size about $600 \times 600$.
- $A$: Toeplitz sparse and symmetric matrix with 4 entries per column. Max size about $40 \times 40$.

I need to solve (for an arbitrary Output matrix $O$, max size $600 \times 40$), the corresponding $I$.

I guess that in the worst case I could compute it as

\begin{equation}
I = R^{-1}OA^{-1}
\end{equation}

but I was wondering if there are faster ways to solve this given the properties of my matrices. I haven't been able to find resources online for my use case, I would appreciate if people can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Computing with the use of $A^{-1}$ is impossible, because $A$ is singular (not invertible). There exist probably some methods, unfortunately, this is not my field.